# SQLite "COUNT(*)" Considered Harmful?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Consider the following simple example:

```
prompt% sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table employee (
           employee_id   integer       primary key,
           first_name    varchar2(32)  not null,
           last_name     varchar2(32)  not null
        );

sqlite> insert into employee (first_name, last_name) values ('Bill', 'Smith');
sqlite> insert into employee (first_name, last_name) values ('Sally', 'Jones');
sqlite> insert into employee (first_name, last_name) values ('Bill', 'Jones');

sqlite> select first_name, count(*) from employee;
```

What will be the result?

The naive might assume it will be:

```
Bill|2
Sally|1
```

But the experienced will notice that the SELECT query is missing the 'GROUP BY' clause.  Oracle, when presented with this query will, in fact, throw up an error:

```
SQL ERROR: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

SQLite, however, doesn't complain, but instead yields:

```
Bill|3
```

which seems bogus to me...  Displaying the total number of rows might make sense, I suppose, but simply picking the last 'first_name' seems rather arbitrary and potentially dangerous.

Is this a bug or a feature that I'm just failing to understand?  Is there a reason SQLite doesn't offer a similar safety net?

Comment: It makes no sense to use an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY` clause when you aren't selecting all rows. Think about, what are you even counting? You want `select first_name, count(*) from employee group by first_name;`

Comment: It could make sense to use an aggregate without a `GROUP BY` if all records are considered to be in a single group (and all you want is the number of records, or the greatest value, or whatever). What doesn't make sense here is the value for `first_name`. This looks like a bug, or at least an extremely poor implementation of SQL.

Comment: It's an identical implementation to MySQL @mwigdahl.

Answer (score 5):

This is all [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query without a GROUP BY
>   clause, then each aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated
>   once across the entire dataset. Each non-aggregate expression in the
>   result-set is evaluated once for an arbitrarily selected row of the
>   dataset. The same arbitrarily selected row is used for each
>   non-aggregate expression...
>
> The single row of result-set data created by evaluating the aggregate
>   and non-aggregate expressions in the result-set forms the result of an
>   aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause. An aggregate query without
>   a GROUP BY clause always returns exactly one row of data, even if
>   there are zero rows of input data.

Simply put, there's no safety net. Don't forget the GROUP BY if you need it.

Comment: Since [SQLite 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html), it is possible to choose the row for non-aggregated expressions with a `MIN` or `MAX`. This is utterly nonstandard, but useful in certain situations.